# How does the MARITIME Act differ from or improve on the IMSC?

Tags: united-states, foreign-policy, legislation, persian-gulf, maritime-security

A UAE think tank had an [article](https://epc.ae/en/details/brief/us-military-s-strategic-doctrine-and-its-approach-to-gulf-security) on Sep 5 saying:

> the US Congress is also increasingly on board with the integrated deterrence doctrine. As part of the 2023 National Defense Authorization Act (NDAA), Congress passed in 2022 the Deterring Enemy Forces and Enabling National Defenses (DEFEND) Act, which authorized the US Defense Secretary to establish an integrated air and missile defense system with Israel and other Middle Eastern partner militaries. The bill enjoyed broad bicameral and bipartisan support when it was introduced. Once it was attached to the NDAA, its path from bill to law was sealed.
>
> Legislators are poised to move further this year. Democratic Sen. Jacky Rosen and Republican Rep. Cathy McMorris Rodgers, with support from fellow congressional Abraham Accords Caucus members, introduced the Maritime Architecture and Response to International Terrorism in the Middle East Act (MARITIME) Act. The follow-up measure would authorize the Defense Department to establish an integrated maritime domain awareness capability with GCC partners to jointly guard waterways in and around the Arabian Peninsula.

But it seems to me the US already has something like the latter, called the [International Maritime Security Construct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Maritime_Security_Construct) (IMSC). How do the provisions of the (proposed) MARITIME Act differ or improve upon that (IMSC)?